# Format the Output in Columns in bash

Tags: bash, string-formatting

Can you help me with formatting the below output in Columns, so when I grep for WWN, I can get a name. It's a big file more than 1000 line's.

If I get one line for one Alias along with its wwn in same line, then it will be awesome.

=============================================================

alias: a_name_A

```
            10:00:00:05:33:00:00:00; 10:00:00:05:12:12:23:00; 
            10:00:00:10:86:00:00:00
```

alias: a_name123_A

```
            20:00:00:10:56:05:12:23; 20:00:00:10:44:04:48:78; 
            20:00:00:10:67:78:90:00
```

alias: a_name2323_A

```
            20:00:00:00:44:33:22:11
```

alias: a_rep02_A

```
            20:00:00:33:33:44:55:55
```

=========================================

Looking Output in CSV format

a_name_A,10:00:00:05:33:00:00:00,10:00:00:05:12:12:23:00,10:00:00:10:86:00:00:00

a_name123_A,20:00:00:10:56:05:12:23,20:00:00:10:44:04:48:78,20:00:00:10:67:78:90:00

a_name2323_A,20:00:00:00:44:33:22:11

a_rep02_A,20:00:00:33:33:44:55:55

Comment: Unfortunately your question only contains requirements: it is not showing any efforts from your side to solve this problem yourself.  Please [edit] your question to show [your attempt far](http://whathaveyoutried.com), and you'll be much more likely to receive answers that help you progress.  Show us your work so far as a [mcve], the result you were expecting and the results you got, and we'll help you figure it out. It may help to re-read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use something like:

```
gawk '/alias/ {
        if(alias=="")
           alias=$2
        else
           {
           print alias data
           data=""
           alias=$2
           }
        next
}
{
        gsub(";",",",$0)
        gsub(" ","",$0)
        data=data $0
}
END {
       print alias data
}' data.txt
```